# Object gets duplicated inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

This is the result I want to achieve

```
dataset: [
    dataset: [
        {
            seriesname: "",
            data: [
                {
                    value: "123",
                },
                {
                    value: "123",
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
]
```

My problem right now is that the second `dataset` gets duplicated.

This is how I am setting it (`val` is an integer and `allYears` is an array of integers):

```
this.grphColumn.dataSource.dataset[0].dataset = this.allYears.map(el => {
    return {
        seriesname: "Planned",
        data: [{value: val}, {value: val}]
    }
});
```

How can I make it so the `dataset` doesn't get duplicated?

Comment: The `.map()` callback is executed for every element of `this.allYears`, hence you most likely want something like: `return { seriesname: "Planned", data: this.allYears.map(...) }`

Comment: And how could I modify `this.grphColumn.dataSource.dataset[0].dataset = this.allYears.map(el => {` to fit that solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the values separately, if you dont want the seriesName to be Repeated..

```
const yearsMap = this.allYears.map((el) => { return { value: el } });

this.grphColumn.dataSource.dataset[0].dataset = {
        seriesname: "Planned",
        data: yearsMap
    }
```